# SQL: check if multiple values in the column SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to check if multiple values are in the column and based on that filter out one of them using a `WHERE` clause?

Obviously this code won't work, but here is the logical example of what I'd like to achieve:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE IF column includes ('value1', 'value2') THEN NOT IN 'value1'
```

example with conditions True:

| column |
| --- |
| value1 |
| value1 |
| value2 |
| value2 |
| value1 |
| value3 |
| value4 |
| value4 |

result:

| column |
| --- |
| value2 |
| value2 |
| value3 |
| value4 |
| value4 |

Side note: process has to be automated as in one upload, dataset might contain value1 which should remain in place and in the next one both of them will be populated and only value2 will be valid.

Comment: you can use 'Column1' LIKE 'Column2' for comparing two columns and using '*' will return all elements in the row.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE POSITION('value1', column) > 0 AND POSITION('value2', column) > 0`
What do you mean by "filter out"?

Comment: By this I mean followin scenario: let say that I have multiple examples of 5 unique values in one column. I want to check whether two distinct of them are both in the set of those 5 and if yes on of the distinct values shouldn't be in the final outp so: WHERE NOT IN value

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide sample data and a sample output for what you are looking for.  How can a column contain 2 values on a record?

Comment: I added the concept of such column into the description @MikeWalton

Comment: But why the need to check if value1 exists or not first?  Just filter out value1 regardless of whether it exists and you get the same result.

Comment: Thing is it has to be automated as one day dataset might contain value 1 which should remain in place and in another upload both of them will be populated and only value2 will be valid.

Comment: This still doesn't make logical sense. Are you saying that you want to filter differently depending on when it is run? if so, make it a stored procedure that accepts a parameter and use that in your where clause.

Comment: @KeithL I don't want to filter at all if both values are not present and I want to filter only value1 when both are present. This is due to change in transactional data in dataset. This is not a static database, it's a data vault continously refreshed and updated with new data.

Comment: I believe you are still going to need a stored procedure or UDTF for this, because what you'd need is a query that evaluates your data and then dynamically builds a SQL statement to filter out what needs to be filtered out.

Comment: @MikeWalton I see, I was afraid that it can't be done using standard sql conditions. Thank you for your analysis

Comment: I could be wrong as I am not fully up to speed on the new Snowflake scripting language, yet.  It's likely possible using that, but not standard SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both val1 and val2 exist then exclude val1 otherwise no filter...

```
declare @t table (col varchar(10))

insert into @t
values
('val1'),('val1'),('val2'),('val3')

select *
from @t
where col <> case when 2 = (select count(*) from (select col from @t where col  in('val1','val2') group by col)a)
             then 'val1'
             else '' end
```

Results:

```
col
val2
val3
```

This is an example when both are not present

```
declare @t2 table (col varchar(10))

insert into @t2
values
('val1'),('val1'),('val3')

select *
from @t2
where col <> case when 2 = (select count(*) from (select col from @t2 where col  in('val1','val2') group by col)a)
             then 'val1'
             else '' end
```

Results:

```
col
val1
val1
val3
```

**Note: the else value needs to be a value that cannot exist in the column col**

**Note2: This is answered using t-sql**

Comment: thank you! that's brilliatly elegant and works!

Comment: @thegreatbudyn You're welcome... if this answered your question, then please accept answer and potentially upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using QUALIFY. The idea is to compare value of the column against an array generated ad-hoc with case expression to handle subsitution logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY NOT ARRAY_CONTAINS(col::VARIANT, 
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT CASE WHEN col IN ('value1', 'value2') THEN 'value1' END) OVER());
```

---

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab AS
SELECT $1 AS col
FROM (VALUES 
      ('value1'), ('value1'), ('value2'), 
      ('value2'), ('value1'), ('value3'),  
      ('value4'), ('value4')
)s;
```

Output:

[image]

---

A more explicit approach is using windowed `COUNT_IF`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY col NOT IN (CASE WHEN COUNT_IF(col IN ('value1', 'value2')) OVER() > 1 
                         THEN 'value1' 
                         ELSE '' 
                    END);
```